# Are CREATE FUNCTION and DROP FUNCTION locking when used inside different transactions?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, concurrency, functions

I'm having a locking issue on PostgreSQL 9.4.5. I run two or more transactions simultaneously (generally there are 2 running at the same time, but 2+ may happen sometimes) reading from the same tables but writing on different output tables. Inside my transactions I have several `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS` and `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` statements that declare some functions.

My guess is that `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS` and `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` are locking. Am I right? I can solve the problem by moving the statement outside the transaction.

I've observed the following: two transactions A and B contains some `DROP FUNCTION` and `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`; if I execute transaction B while transaction A is still running, transaction B waits on the first `DROP FUNCTION` statements it encounters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Yes of course the other transaction will wait. (Nearly) Every DDL statement takes an exclusive lock on the object being modified (dropped, created). See [Explicit Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) in the documentation.